# How do I eliminate system admin application permanently on my Android phone

Tags: uninstallation, device-administrator, tecno-n3

My friend registered on an app with my phone to get a loan from the PalmPay application. The management asked him to install an app before the loan will be given to him, they say the application will be for the assurance that the loan will be paid back, and the security plugin application was installed on my phone as an admin application. He has paid back the loan but now I think someone is using the application to have access to all my details.

I decided to remove the application, but I can't permanently delete the admin application from my phone before they do something very bad with my phone. They are already on my Facebook account/Instagram account. They are trying to get more from me. I can just restive a message from Amazon and other important platforms that I usually keep my money. They are trying to reset my password to all.

Please, I need help to protect my Android phone from them. Please, I really need help before they do something very bad and wicked to me

Comment: I would try a factory reset on the phone. Not sure it would work - and it would remove everything from it...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Security -> Advanced -> Device admin apps. Find the app and disable it's admin status.

Uninstall the app and restart your device.

If you downloaded it from Google Play Store, go there and report it. In Google Play Store it's called "flag as inappropriate", and there's an option "Harmful to device or data" that would be fitting.

If it was downloaded from another service you can attempt to report it to them, and it may even help if it's an official big-name third-party like Samsung App Store. If it was some shady third-party then hopefully you've learned something about security.

---

If the password reset requests happened within one day it is somewhat likely to be this app. If it was over multiple days it could still be the app, but it would seem more likely your "friend" is nothing of the sort.